# Find working without transaction in JTA

Tags: java, jpa, jta

i'm studying JTA and i tried make a find example to test my concept:

First a created a class with CDI injeting my DAO:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SegurancaServiceJTA {

    @Inject
    private DAOSeguranca daoSeguranca;

    @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.NEVER)
    public void findTest(){
        List result = daoSeguranca.findList("SELECT u FROM Usuario u",null);
    }

}
```

Inside my DAO i'm injeting my EntityManager with @PersistenceContext annotation.

```
public class DAOSeguranca implements IDAO, Serializable {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "seguranca")
    private EntityManager em;

     @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    public List findList(String hql, Map<String, Object> namedParams, Integer first,
                                                   Integer maxResult, Class qualifier, boolean buscarTodos) {
        try {
            logger.debug("Executando findList. HQL = " + hql);
            Query query = em.createQuery(hql);
            configureParams(namedParams, query);

            if (first != null) {
                query.setFirstResult(first);
            }

            if (maxResult != null) {
                query.setMaxResults(maxResult);
            } else if (!buscarTodos) {
                query.setMaxResults(100);
            }

            return query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
            throw new DAOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

My doubt are:

1) I understand that this method should not work because entityManager can find anything without a transaction, and i'm using TxType.NEVER to force error. But this method works normal and return the beans.

2) In my persistence.xml i'm using JTA, but if i put RESOURCE_LOCAL everything continue working. So, this is right ? I understand that JTA should work only with JTA in persistence.xml and not RESOURCE_LOCAL.

Comment: can add the DAO definition and that method impl?

Comment: Sure. I already putted

Comment: can you add the package of @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.NEVER)? Also is this EJB or Spring based backend?

Comment: I'm using this packaged: import javax.transaction.Transactional. I am not using EJB or SPring, just CDI + JTA 1.2 + Jboss EAP 7

Comment: Its no good to ask two questions at once, it makes the question too broad. Re: your first question, it is not required to have a running transaction to fetch data. The effect is that all entities fetched are instantly detached, which means lazy loaded properties cannot be loaded and any changes to the entities are not persisted unless merge() is called.

Comment: So, if i use TxType.NEVER the JTA create a transaction in instant of em.createQuery ? But transaction exists right?